# Example of two convergent series whose product is not convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could someone give me an example of two convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n$ diverges?

Answer (score 19):

$$a_n = b_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ where $n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$

Comment: Why did you put $\sqrt{n+1}$ in the denominator instead of $\sqrt n$? It seems to me that it would work either way.

Comment: @MarkDominus Yes. Just to start my $n$ from $0$.

Comment: Hmm, the two series are only conditionally convergent. Are there also examples where they are absolutely convergent?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133400/what-are-the-rules-for-convergence-for-2-series-that-are-added-subtracted-multip)

Answer (score 0):

I am merely fleshing the above answer out. It took some work to prove that for $${{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{a_n}={{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n+1}}={{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{b_n}$$ the product is not convergent. One checks that $$c_n = {a_0}{b_n}+\cdots {a_n}{b_0}=(-1)^n{{\sum}^{n}_{k=0}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-k+1)(k+1)}}}.$$
Now, we observe that $$(n-k+1)(k+1)=({\frac{n}{2}}+1)^2-({\frac{n}{2}}-k)^2\leq ({\frac{n}{2}}+1)^2.$$ Thus, $$|c_n|\geq {{\sum}^{n}_{k=0}}{\frac{2}{n+2}}={\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2}}.$$ Now, as $n\rightarrow {\infty},$ $${\frac{2(n+1)}{n+2}}\rightarrow{2}.$$ But this implies that $|c_n|$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\rightarrow{\infty}.$ Hence, $${{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{c_n}={{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{a_n}\cdot{{\sum}^{\infty}_{n=0}}{b_n}$$ cannot converge.