# Divergence of sum of reciprocals of square-free numbers

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I am aware that there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272587/is-the-sum-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-squarefree-numbers-divergent-or-convergent), however I want to prove that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ square free diverges, *without* relying on the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ diverges for $p$ prime. This is equivalent to proving that $\sum \frac{|\mu(n)|}{n}$ converges, where $\mu(n)$ is the mobius function.  I would like verification that my proof is correct:

**My Proof:**
We begin by noting that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, and so $$c * \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ must also converge for any positive integer $c$. Therefore, if we look at the sum $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ ranges only through the integers that are **not** squarefree, then this sum must converge because it is the composition of a series of convergent sums.  Since $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, we must have the sum of the reciprocals of square-free integers also diverging.

In particular, how can I be sure that the sum of the reciprocals of non square-free integers converges? It seems like we are taking an infinite number of convergent sums, which doesn't have to necessarily converge.

Comment: Looks like you are taking a divergent series minus an absolute convergent series...that should be obvious...

Comment: Yes but I was asking for verification of the correctness of the proof.

Comment: Check this out, maybe it helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133400/what-are-the-rules-for-convergence-for-2-series-that-are-added-subtracted-multip

Comment: Thanks.  But more specifically, we are adding what seems to be an infinite number of convergent series, namely the ones that are of the form  c * 1/n^2.  How can we be sure that this still converges?

Comment: The sum of *not* squarefrees contains $\sum \frac1{4n}$, hence diverges

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.  How can I go about verifying that the sum of squarefrees will diverge then?(without using the reciprocals of the primes)

Comment: One can estimate the sum of the reciprocals of numbers divisible by $4$ up  to $n$, the sum of the reciprocals of numbers divisible by $9$ up fo $n$, and so on.  Don't worry about overlap. Add up.  Compare with $\ln n$.

Comment: So you would end up getting that the sum of non-squarefree reciprocals diverges.  But how would I show the same for squarefree reciprocals?

Comment: That's not the point. The sum I am referring to is in the long run less than about $\ln n$ times $\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots$. This is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$, which is nicely less than $1$. We don't need to know the exact sum $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$, a reasonably good upper bound will do.  So the sum of the reciprocals of square-frees up to $n$ is bounded below by a non-zero constant times $\ln n$.

Comment: Oh wow I understand.  A very nice argument.  Thank you!

Comment: Isn't OP's proof basically correct, though, if composition is taken to mean "(Cauchy) product"? I mean, if $\sum_{q\,\text{squarefree}} q^{-1}$ were to converge, we would have $\sum_n \frac 1n = \sum_{\substack{n=q\,m^2\\q\,\text{squarefree}, m >0}} \frac 1{q\,m^2} =  \left(\sum_{q\,\text{squarefree}} q^{-1}\right) \times \left(\sum_m \frac 1{m^2}\right) < +\infty$, which is absurd.

Comment: @PseudoNeo: Please consider writing an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outline: Let $n$ be large. Note that the sum of the reciprocals of the integers up to $n$ is about $\ln n$.

The sum of the reciprocals of multiples of $4$ up to $n$ is less than roughly $\frac{1}{4}\ln n$. Here we are already giving away a bit, since this reciprocal sum is actually about $\frac{1}{4}\ln(n/4)$.

The sum of the reciprocals of multiples of $9$ up to $n$ is less than roughly $\frac{1}{9}\ln n$. And so on.

So the sum of the reciprocals of not square-frees up to $n$ is less than roughly 
$$(\ln n)\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots.\right).$$
The infinite sum above is upper bounded by 
$$(\ln n)\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}+\cdots\right),$$ which is less than $\frac{1}{2}\ln n$. (Since we are upper-bounding, we don't need to worry about overlap.)

So the sum of the reciprocals of the square-frees up to $n$ is asymptotically greater than $\frac{1}{2}\ln n$.

Comment: $(\ln n) (\frac 1{3\cdot 4} + \cdots )$ is a lower bound of the infinite sum right above that.

Comment: @i707107: Thanks, I was missing the first two terms, separated out for the estimate.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Q(x)$ be the number of square-free positive integers $n\leq x$. It is well-known that 
$$
Q(x) = \frac 6{\pi^2} x + O(\sqrt x).
$$
We now apply partial summation:
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{n} = \frac {Q(t)}t \bigg\vert_{1-}^x + \int_1^x \frac{Q(t)}{t^2} dt = \frac 6{\pi^2} \log x+O(1). 
$$
Thus, the sum of reciprocals of square-free numbers diverges, as $\log x \rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

André Nicolas's proof is impeccable, but I'd like to give another one, which is probably closer to yours.

Let's recall that a family $(a_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of nonnegative numbers is *summable* is the set of finite sums $\left\{ \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda'} a_\lambda \,\middle|\, \Lambda' \subset \Lambda\text{ finite}\right\}$ is bounded. In that case, the least upper bound of this set is the *sum* of the family, and we denote it $\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda$. This theory is basically equivalent to the theory of series (which corresponds to $\Lambda = \mathbb N$) if $\Lambda$ is countable, which is the only interesting case.

The result I'd like to use is the following, which corresponds to [the Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_infinite_series) of ordinary series.

**Theorem.** Let $(a_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in\Lambda}$ and $(b_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ be two families of nonnegative numbers. If these two families are summable, then so is $(a_\lambda\,b_\mu)_{(\lambda, \mu)_\in\Lambda\times M}$, and we have the equality
$$\sum_{(\lambda,\mu)\in \Lambda \times M} a_\lambda\,b_\mu = \left(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} a_\lambda\right) \, \left(\sum_{\mu\in M} b_\mu\right).$$

Now, let $S = \{1, 4, 9, 16,\ldots\}$ and $SF = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10,\ldots\}$ be the sets of square and squarefree numbers, respectively.

You already know that $(n^{-1})_{n \in\mathbb N^*}$ isn't summable and that $(n^{-1})_{n\in S}$ is (because that's really equivalent to saying that $\sum \frac 1{m^2}$ converges). I claim that the above theorem directly shows that these two properties imply that $(n^{-1})_{n\in SF}$ isn't summable.

Indeed, if $(n^{-1})_{n\in SF}$ were summable, so would $(a^{-1}\,b^{-1})_{(a,b)\in S\times SF}$, as per the theorem. But it is easy to show that every positive number can be written in a unique way as the product of a square number and a squarefree number. So, this product family $(a^{-1}\,b^{-1})_{(a,b)\in S\times SF}$ is really the same thing as $(n^{-1})_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$, so it cannot be summable, which proves that $(n^{-1})_{n\in SF}$ wasn't summable either.

Comment: At its core, this argument is more elementary than the others. No precise knowledge of the size of $\Sigma 1/n^2$ required, just that it converges. +1