# What is the proof of the theorem that the series of reciprocals of square-free numbers diverges?

Tags: divergent-series

I am not a mathematician. I am reading David Applebaum's book "Limits, limits everywhere ", in which he gives a proof of the divergence of the series of square-free numbers on page 91. I don't understand where he gets the inequality that he uses to prove the theorem. I also don't understand whether the three sums in the inequality run over the same limits. Any light shed on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverge.  See, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divergence of sum of reciprocals of square-free numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875441/divergence-of-sum-of-reciprocals-of-square-free-numbers)

Comment: @lulu Very good point, we can even strenghten this (although for the question the primes are enough) : The sum of the reciprocals of the primes of the form $an+b$ with $n$ posisitive integer diverges whenever $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers.

Comment: @lulu These are in a sense equivalent. The sum of reciprocals of the square-free numbers is the product of $1 + 1/p$ over primes $p$.  The infinite product  $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ (where $a_n > 0$) diverges iff $\sum_n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Oh, agreed.  I should note that the duplicate I linked to specifically seeks to avoid using the fact that $\sum \frac 1p$ diverges...thinking that the OP might find those arguments more elementary.